# Loop and decrease counter not working - assembly

Tags: loops, assembly

I am new to assembly language and was asked to have a program that will allow only three chances of error when typing the password in.

```
s:
    main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 3

again:
    mov ah, 9 
    lea dx, a
    int 21h
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, '*'
    int 21h
    mov ah, 8
    int 21h
    mov bl, al
    mov ah, 2
    cmp bl, 'Y'
    je second
    cmp bl, 'y'
    je second
    jne iinvalid

second:
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, '*'
    int 21h
    mov ah, 8
    int 21h
    mov bh, al
    mov ah, 2
    cmp bh, 'E'
    je third
    cmp bh, 'e'
    je third
    jne iinvalid

third:
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, '*'
    int 21h
    mov ah, 8
    int 21h
    mov cl, al
    mov ah, 2
    cmp cl, 'S'
    je welcome
    cmp cl, 's'
    je welcome
    jne iinvalid

iinvalid: 
jmp invalid

checking:
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, i
        int 21h
        jmp exit

togo:
    loop again

welcome:
        mov ah,9
        lea dx, c
        int 21h
        lea dx, d
        int 21h
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov bl, al

            newp:
                mov ah, 9
                lea dx, i
                int 21h
                jmp exit

invalid: 
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, b
        int 21h
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov cl, al
        cmp cl, 'Y'
        je togo
        cmp cl, 'y'
        je togo
        jne exit

exit:
       mov ah, 4ch
       int 21h
       main endp
       end s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  destroy the content of cx inside the loop.
easiest way to fix it:

```
    mov cx, 3

again:
    push cx                   ; save loop cnt on stack
    mov ah, 9 
    ...

togo:
    pop cx                    ; restore cnt from stack
    loop again
```

keep in mind, that if you jump out of the loop, cx must still be removed from stack

```
welcome:
    pop cx                   ; purge cnt from stack
    mov ah,9
```

just a hint:

you compare the characters entered, to be either lowercase, or uppercase
uppercase and lowercase characters are (in ascii) identically, except of bit 0x20. you could "mask out" this bit by an AND with 0xDF ( 1101 1111 binary), and check the characters with just a single branch (instead of 3):

```
cmp bl, 'Y'
je second
cmp bl, 'y'
je second
jne iinvalid
```

--->

```
and bl, 0xdf           ; make lowercase to uppercase
cmp bl, 'Y'            ; THEN here both 'y' and 'Y' match
jne iinvalid
```

Comment: It's other way around, `and bl, 0xdf` will convert lowercase ASCII to uppercase ASCII, so next `cmp` has to work with `'Y'`. Or the mangling can be done the other way `or bl,0x20`, converting uppercase ASCII into lowercase, then `cmp bl,'y'` should work.